# VIM open file from within :shell command

Tags: vim

Lets say I issue :shell command from withing VI. Then I navigate to a directory and decide that I need to edit foo.txt file which I see there. Is there a way to return back to vi from the shell and have foo.txt opened for editing

Comment: The emacs-ification of vim proceeds apace, I see.  Remember when vi was the fast small editor you used because you didn't want to wait for emacs to open?  I do.

Comment: What would you want vi to do with the currently opened file? You can run vi on foo.txt from the shell, and when you're done, exit the shell and you'll be back in vi editing the original file.

Comment: @Paul: The difference being that :shell doesn't open a shell window in Vim.  It backgrounds Vim, leaving you in the shell you were using when you invoked Vim.

Answer (score 4):

Given the following conditions are satisfied, there is a way to achieve what you want.

- Vim is built with `+clientserver`.  You can check this with `:echo has('clientserver')`.
- You are in an environment that can and is properly configured to communicate with an X server.
- You use the `--servername` option and a relevant argument to it when starting Vim.

In this case, you can make use of the [--remote](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html#--remote) option for Vim.

An example session would be:

```
vim --servername foo somefile.txt
:shell
<do stuff in your shell>
vim --servername foo --remote otherfile.txt
fg
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question says vi, but your tag says vim.  I don't know how to make the shell you invoke talk back to the parent Vim window, but in case the following does what you want anyway:

`:E` invokes Vim's file system navigator.  `:help netrw` gives more information on it.  From there, you can cruise around in the file system until you find the file you're interested in, press `Enter`, and start editing it.