# How to open another file in background Vim from Bash command-line?

Tags: linux, vim, command-line

I am transitioning from using Gvim to console Vim.

I open a file in Vim, and then suspend Vim, run a few commands on the command-line and then want to return to Vim.

- `Ctrl+Z` (in normal mode) suspends Vim and drops back to the console
- `fg` can be used to return focus to Vim
- `jobs` lists background jobs and can be used to get the job number to
    bring a given job to the foreground (e.g., `fg %2` to bring job 2 to the
    foreground).

However, when Vim is in the background and I issue `vim file`, the file opens in a new instance of Vim.

I'm used to using the `--remote` option with Gvim to open a file in an existing Gvim instance.

#### Question:

- How can I open another file in a background Vim from the command-line?
- Is this a reasonable workflow for moving between console and Vim?

#### Update:

I just read [this answer by @jamessan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546507/vim-open-file-from-within-shell-command/2546724#2546724) which provides a few ideas. He shows the following code snippet:

```
vim --servername foo somefile.txt
:shell
<do stuff in your shell>
vim --servername foo --remote otherfile.txt
fg
```

However, I'd have to think about how to make it easier to use perhaps with some aliases.

- Would this be a good approach?
- How could it be made efficient to use?

Answer (score 7):

This is also what I need. I found this thread, though no satisfying approach, happy to see people having same requirement like me.

My approach is

## add below to .bashrc

```
v() {
    vim_id=`jobs|sed -n "/vim/s/\[\([0-9]\)\]+.*/\1/p"`
    if [ -n "$vim_id" ]; then
        echo "tabedit $@" > ~/.vim_swap/e.vim && fg $vim_id
    else
        vim $@
    fi
}
```

## add below to .vimrc

```
nnoremap <silent> <space>e :source $HOME/.vim_swap/e.vim<Bar>:call writefile([], $HOME."/.vim_swap/e.vim")<CR>
```

Then `v foo.c` to open first file, editing..., ctrl-z to suspend vim, do shell stuff, `v bar.h` to bring vim foreground.

And in VIM, press `<Space>e` to tabedit bar.h.

So the idea is to generate vim command from shell command, save them to a temp .vim file. In VIM, map key to source the .vim file and clear it.

Comment: nice. This isn't much shorter than just doing `fg` followed by `:e foo.txt`, but if you forget to fg, this saves the situation.

Comment: Would there be an event that we can use here instead of the manual `<Space>e` ?

Comment: @trusktr No, more than that. If you vim's current directory is not the same as you shell CWD, you can enhance this solution with "readlink -f" to get absolute path and it works great.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of running vim again, you need to bring your current vim process to the foreground (with fg) and open the file in vim.

I have not used it much, but you may find the "vim server" feature (see --remote*, --servername, etc. options) lets you open the file from your shell into an existing, backgrounded vim.  However, ctrl-z *suspends* the process instead of allowing it to continue to run in the background, and you will need to put that vim into the background so it can respond as a "vim server".  Use the shell's bg command to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that I could bring back Vim and open files within Vim. It's helpful to know that this might be the standard option. But it seemed to me that this might be less than efficient at times. E.g., I suspend from Vim to the console and move to a completely different directory where it's easy for me to open a file from the command-line. If I were to open Vim, I'd be back in the previous working directory and have to navigate the file system again.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim: If I want to start on something completely separate, I'll generally open another instance of vim.  Otherwise, within the same "thing", the directories aren't too far away.  The netrw plugin, which comes with vim (at least it did when I built vim 7.3 from source), lets you "edit" directories (try ":e .") and browse that way.  There are other "find file" plugins you may like.

Answer (score 3):

I would just call vim from `fg` and open new file inside vim since its just seems to be faster (although it may be just faster to me). To work with multiple files inside vim you need to use command edit (in vim): `:e [filepath/]filename` and you walk true buffers (all files will be as vim buffers) with `^I` (ctrl+I) and `^O` (ctrl+o)

It works on both GTK and shell versions. There is no such a huge difference on workflow. I prefer shell version since i do most of commands there (compiling launching etc.).

Comment: Just noticed that i wrote `e:` instead of `:e`. Fixed

Answer (score 2):

If you use `tmux`, and if you always have your vim instance running as the first job in background, you can setup alias like below in csh.

```csh
alias v 'tmux send-keys fg Space +1 Enter :e Space `realpath \!:1` Enter'
```

then you can call it like this

```
v myfile.txt
```

If your vim instance is not the first background job, enrich the alias with `jobs` output.

In Bash, this can be done with a function.

```sh
function v() {
    local job=$(jobs | perl -ne 'print $1 if /\[(\d+)\].*vim/')
    if [[ -n $job ]]; then
        tmux send-keys fg Space $job Enter
        for f in $*; do
            tmux send-keys :e Space `realpath $f` Enter
        done
    else
        vim $*
    fi
}
```

Comment: This `perl` formula fails if any `vim` string appears at non-command position in `jobs` output, e.g. `man vim` or `less mkenvimage.bb` even if both "good" `vim ..` and "false" `foo vim..` appear in jobs.